# How to scroll to certain div using Javascript in two pages

Tags: javascript

I have a compare button that appears in two different pages in my project. When I click on it calls a javascript function. I want to edit this function so it does the following: first to determine which page i'm in and then scroll up to a certain DIV in this page

Here is the function:

```
$(function() {

  $('.cont_fontsicon').click(function compareProduct(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("currentId : "+currentId)
    if(currentId.search("#") > 0){
        var span= $(this).find('span.icon-copy_icon.icon_circle_base.icon_gray_878881.bord_rad30.selected');

        if ($(this).find('span').is('.selected')){
            return false;
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        var valueSplit=currentId.split('+#+');
        var currentIdCat=valueSplit[0];
        var currentIdStr=valueSplit[1];
        var currentPrdType=valueSplit[2];
        var resultClassName = $("#prodBoxId"+currentIdStr).attr('class');               
        var catId = document.getElementById("category_list").value;
        var catIdStr = catId.trim();    
        var listSize = document.getElementById("productlistSize").value;
        var comparisonProductType = document.getElementById("productType").value;
        var catEndecaId=currentIdCat;   
        var catEndecaIdStr = catEndecaId.trim();
        var userHead=document.getElementById("userHeader").value;
        var errorMessagesValue=document.getElementById("errorMessagesContainer").value;
        if(catIdStr == 0){  
            addProductToComparisonList(currentIdStr,$(this),listSize);
        }

        /*To be uncommented if we get more than one type of product for one category
         * 
         * if(catIdStr == catEndecaIdStr && currentPrdType==comparisonProductType){ */
        else if(catIdStr == catEndecaIdStr ){
            if(userHead.search("Android")>0 || userHead.search("Mobi")>0)
                {  if(listSize<2 ){
                    addProductToComparisonList(currentIdStr,$(this),listSize);
                          }
                      else
                          {

                          $("#prodBoxId"+currentIdStr).append('<div class="error_message"><div class="cont_img_alert inline_block"></div><span class="text_error_message inline_block">'+errorMessagesValue.compare2Products+'</span></div>');
                          var divPosition = $('#prodBoxId'+currentIdStr+' .error_message').offset();
                          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");

                          }
                     }
        else
                {
               if(listSize<3){
                   addProductToComparisonList(currentIdStr,$(this),listSize);
                             }
                  else
                      $("#prodBoxId"+currentIdStr).append('<div class="error_message"><div class="cont_img_alert inline_block"></div><span class="text_error_message inline_block">'+errorMessagesValue.compare3Products+'</span></div>'); 
                        var divPosition = $('#prodBoxId'+currentIdStr+' .error_message').offset();
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");

                    }
              }

        //Fix for defect# 1660
        if(catIdStr != 0 && catIdStr != catEndecaIdStr ){
        $("#prodBoxId"+currentIdStr).append('<div class="error_message"><div class="cont_img_alert inline_block"></div><span class="text_error_message inline_block">'+errorMessagesValue.compareSameCategory+'</span></div>'); 
            var divPosition = $('#prodBoxId'+currentIdStr+' .error_message').offset();
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "fast");
        }
    }  
    else {              
        var loggedInUser = document.getElementById("checkLoggedIn").value;
        if(loggedInUser == 'true')
              {
              document.getElementById(currentId).href = '#';
            /*showPopUp("wishlist",currentId);*/
              $(this).closest('div').find('a#customPopup').trigger("click");

             }
          else
              {
              document.getElementById(currentId).submit();
              }

    }
});
```